# How to check if NSDictionay key has a value efficiently when creating XML

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, nsarray, null

I am creating some XML in objective C, I know how to do it however there is the possibility that there could be 800+ values I might be putting into XML, which I am getting from a NSArray of NSDictionaries.

So I was wondering if there is an efficient way of checking for nill or null in a keyvalue that's of type NSString.

Currently this is what my code looks like:

```
     NSMutableArray *xmlItems = [coreDataController readInstallForXML:selectedInstallID];

    for (int i = 0; i < [xmlItems count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *currentXMLItem = [xmlItems objectAtIndex:i];

        [xmlWriter writeStartElement:@"Items"];
            [xmlWriter writeAttribute:@"insID" value:[currentXMLItem valueForKey:@"insID"]];
// there are about another 20 attributes I have to add here.
    }

// then write end elemtent etc.
```

In the code above I have no added any checking but I was hoping someone might have something better for me than adding a bunch of `if` statements for each attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NSDictionary allKeysForObject:] to get all keys for the 'nil' values, so you have a list of keys to ignore.

Generating 800 items is not necessarily 'much' or 'slow'. You don't want to do that on the main thread anyway, so just make sure you perform it as a background operation.

Comment: say when I am looping through creating each of the Items, the current NSdictionary Object could have different values to the next one (i.e. say one key might be nill till the next itteration of the loop then it might not be nill... how dose allKeysForObject work then?

Comment: How do you have nil values as key?
Get the 'allKeysForObject:' only once before you are iterating through the dictionary. In the loop you can check the key against 'allKeysForObject' results to ignore all nill values.

Answer (score 0):

use the allKeys method on the NSDictionary to return an NSArray of keys; then iterate through that array and for each key retrieve the value from the dictionary and use one if statement to check the string before writing out the xml element

Comment: But wont that be slow if I have 20 if statments and 800 items in the array.  havent showen it in my code but I have about 20 attributes I still need to add.

Comment: the data is the same for whether you write 20 lines or loop 1 line 20 times - I thought you wanted 'something better ... than adding a bunch of IF statements for each attribute'

Comment: Oh okay, well I guess I missunderstood you. I have never used allKeys before Im just trying to find some information on it now.

Comment: is there any chance of a small peice of example code? I just have never used this feature before.